# trouble passing variable arguments list in powerhsell

Tags: powershell, sccm, application, packaging

Looking to build a small package for deploying Project 64 bit click to run version.  I want to use MECM

Install files get copied to somewhere in `c:\windows\ccmcache\*`

```
$fire_off_location = Get-Location  #I use this to get current location of where the install files are

Start-Process -FilePath $fire_off_location\setup.exe -ArgumentList "/configure $fire_off_location\ProjectPro2019_32.xml" -Wait -PassThru
```

I am trying to replicate a standard install using the office deployment tool method here.  the only problem is getting the argument to read `"/configure c:\windows\ccmcache\2\ProjectPro2019_32.xml"`

The folder in `ccmcache` could be anything, whatever MECM decides to create, which is why I want to use the variable.  no matter what I try I can't get the formatting right for powershell to read what the file path will be in the argument list.

Comment: Are the setup and configuration file always going to be in the directory with eachother?

Comment: Hey Robbie.  Thanks for reaching out.  I finally figured it out.  yes, the setup and config files are always going to be in that same working directory, whatever SCCM decides to create at the time the package gets copied out there.  My quotes were messed up in my variable.  Once I got them in the right area, it saw the correct string in the argument list.

Comment: Glad you figured it out! If the files are always in the same directory, you don't need to include $fire_off_location in the /configure section. You can just do ".\ProjectPro2019_32.xml". The .\ means run from the same directory.

Comment: I will give that a shot as well.  I do like power shell, but the syntax makes me want to jump off a bridge sometimes! oh well, will keep at it and it will get easier.  thank you!

Comment: I had the same issue when I first started working with it, but when you get the hang of always living as an object in the pipeline, everything makes a lot more sense.